# "Namespacing" an import in systemJS

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I want to use a library [ip-address](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address) with SystemJS (note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534182/import-lodash-incrementally-with-ng-cli) may look similar but it is a different problem I ran into trying while trying to accomplish this task).

The library ip-address depends on util-deprecate.  It imports it as follows:

```
var util = require('util');
```

And then uses it as follows:

```
Address4.prototype.toV6Group =
  util.deprecate(Address4.prototype.toGroup6,
    'deprecated: `toV6Group` has been renamed to `toGroup6`');
```

When I import ip-address in a node project as...

```
var ipAddress = require('ip-address');
```

...then I don't get any problems.

When I import ip-address in a SystemJS project...

```
System.import('ip-address');
```

...then I get an error:

```
util.deprecate is not a function
```

How can I configure SystemJS to perform this import?  Currently I am configuring it as so...

```
const map: any = {
  'ip-address':'vendor/ip-address',
  'util':'vendor/util-deprecate'
}

const packages: any = {
  'ip-address': {main:'ip-address.js'},
  'util': {main: 'browser'}
};
```

Just to save a lookup, the util-deprecate's browser.js file is [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/util-deprecate/blob/master/browser.js), it is exporting the deprecate function directly.

Note, I can get this to work if I modify the ip-address module so that all calls are of the form:

```
Address4.prototype.toV6Group =
  util(Address4.prototype.toGroup6,
    'deprecated: `toV6Group` has been renamed to `toGroup6`');
```

I'd rather not modify a 3rd-party library if I can avoid it however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it turns out the issue was that I *thought* the `ip-address` module was using `util-deprecate`.  It turns out that the way the `ip-address` module was importing util...

```
var util = require('util');
```

It was not importing `util-deprecate` but importing Node's built in package `util`.  So, in order for `ip-address` to truly use `util-deprecate` a change will have to be made to the `ip-address` module.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged with [jspm](/questions/tagged/jspm) there's a pretty simple solution.

Using `jspm` you can simply install [ip-address](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address) right from `npm` using:

```
jspm install npm:ip-address
```

which will do all the dependency management for you.

I've tested this in the browser and node.js using the example code `ip-address` provides:

```
import {Address6} from 'ip-address'

const address = new Address6('2001:0:ce49:7601:e866:efff:62c3:fffe');

console.log(address.isValid());  // true

const teredo = address.inspectTeredo();

console.log(teredo.client4);  // '157.60.0.1'
```

and it works totally fine.

Comment: It was fixed 4 days ago https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address/pull/34

Comment: @Pace ohh sweet so that's why it works. Well it just wasn't clear from your question if that's what you had tried.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion.